# How to find out my car's specs?

Tags: figures

I purchased my car second-hand a couple of years ago but I'm not sure anymore what are its exact specs, for instance in terms of engine power and stuff. Is there a way to know this easily, maybe some online database or something? The vehicle is a Citroen C3 Desire from 2003 with a 1360cc engine.

Answer (score 2):

If the car has an owner's manual, then you can find the details under technical specifications, which is usually the last section

Model series - Citroen C3[A8]
Engine code - KFV
Engine designation - TU3JP
Capacity - 1,36 L
Cylinders - 4
Power - 55 kW/ 75PS

Model series - Citroen C3[A8] 16V
Engine code - KFU
Engine designation - ET3J4
Capacity - 1,36 L
Cylinders - 4
Power - 65 kW/ 88PS

Comment: Thanks. It does show the engine size, but amazingly it shows engine power nowhere!! I checked and rechecked all ownership and insurance documents I have, it appears nowhere. As if it wasn't worth mentioning. Welcome to Britain...

Comment: If you can share the vehicle details then I can help you find information

Comment: Ok, it's a Citroen C3 Desire from 2003 with a 1360cc engine.

Comment: Details added, please check in the answer

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I checked thoroughly but they don't appear anywhere in the car manual...

Answer (score 2):

Next time it may be easy to check it out yourself. There are plenty of free online car databases. I use [carspecs360.com](http://carspecs360.com) which gives you all the desired information.

Answer (score 0):

well,no offense,but people usually do a little research before purchasing a car. 
you can find the info in your owner's manual which you must have had with the car. if not, try some [online car database](https://www.auto-data.net/en/citroen-c3-model-1690), like this.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to get info about your car, lacking anything else: You can ask a certified dealer to look up you VIN in their system. You´ll find the VIN in your cars papers, and also on different locations imprinted into the frame, and on the lower right corner on your windscreen.

For more info [see here](https://www.safelite.com/windshield-auto-glass-technology/vin)

Your car manufacturer has a detailed database of the cars they sold and their vin´s. It´s also a good Idea to see if those numbers match the documentation upon purchase.